# Django rendering issue eager loaded data

Tags: django, django-templates, many-to-many, eager-loading

Those are many models

```
class FacultyMember(models.Model):
    # some attributes

    @staticmethod
    def get_profile_information(id, first_name, last_name):
        return get_object_or_404(FacultyMember.objects.filter(
            pk=id,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name
        ).prefetch_related('project_set').prefetch_related('publication_set'))


class Publication(models.Model):
    # some attributes
    author = models.ManyToManyField(FacultyMember, blank=True)

class Project(models.Model):
    # some attributes
    researchers = models.ManyToManyField(FacultyMember, blank=True)
```

And this is my view

```
def profile(request, id, first_name, last_name):
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {
        'faculty': FacultyMember.get_profile_information(
            id, first_name, last_name
         )
    })
```

I try render those data in template as following code

```
{% for i in faculty.project_set %}
    <li>
        {{ i.title }}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Than I get following error message

**'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable**

-> **{% for i in faculty.project_set %}**

How to render eager loaded data in django template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because `faculty.project_set` is a manager, not a queryset.

Just as you have to do `Faculty.objects.all()` or `Faculty.objects.filter(...)` instead of simply `Faculty.objects`, you need to call a method on the project set, like `faculty.objects.all()`

In the Django template language, you don't use parentheses to call the method, so you would do:

```
{% for project in faculty.project_set.all %}
```

This is unrelated to whether you use `prefetch_related` or not.

Comment: Yes, I see that my query do not load data with eager way, although I use prefetch_related. Please explain more that how to load data with single query that  have inner join , if it is best practice in my case.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Looping through the projects in the template is separate from whether you use `prefetch_related` or not. In your case, it looks like you only have one `Faculty` member, so `prefetch_related` won't save you any queries. You can't do any better than one query to fetch the faculty, and one query for each related many to many relationship.

Comment: According to my sql knowledge it is possible fetching faculty and loading faculty information and his projects and his publications data with single query that have inner join statement. In this point, I ask two question. Firstly, how to write that query in django orm. Secondly, is this (loading all data with one query) best practice in django logic.

Comment: The ORM is not always as efficient as theoretically possible, but you gain convenience and readability. Django best practice would be to use the ORM, and accept one query for each many to many relationship, unless it's causing unacceptable performance. I'm sure it's possible to manually write more efficient SQL. However, you can't use the ORM to do that, and it will complicate your code.

Answer (score 1):

**Replace:**

```
FacultyMember.objects.filter(
        pk=id,
        first_name=first_name,
        last_name=last_name
    ).prefetch_related('project_set').prefetch_related('publication_set')
```

**to:**

```
FacultyMember.objects.filter(
        pk=id,
        first_name=first_name,
        last_name=last_name
    )
```

**In template, you can use:**

```
{% for i in faculty.project_set.all %}
```

Comment: I try to load all data with single query however your answer will send extra query for each relation. I think loading data with this way is not best practice.